# UI Dialog opens multiple times

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am opening dialog onclick of button,If I have clicked multiple times,then dialog opens twice.I dont want the top most small dialog to appear,I need only dialog which is behind.
Same data is showing in both dialogs.
See image attached

I am using below code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#policyDialog").html("");
    $('#policyDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
    });
});

function onViewDetails(policyID) {
    var policyID = policyID;
    var policydetaildialog = "";
    var title = "title";

    $(".loading").css({
        'display': 'block'
    });
    $('#policyDialog').dialog({
        width: 1000,
        autoResize: false,
        draggable: false,
        hide: null,
        modal: true,
        height: "auto",
        maxHeight: 500,
        maxWidth: 1000,
        minHeight: 450,
        minWidth: 450,
        title: title,
        close: function (e) {
            //e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "xyz.jsp",
        data: {
            dataID: policyID
        },
        success: function (response) {
            //$("#policyDialog").html(response);
            policydetaildialog = response;
            $("#policyDialog").dialog('open');
            //$("#policyDialog").html(policydetaildialog);
            $("#policyDialog").html(response);
        },
        dataType: "html",
        async: false
    });

    /* $("#policyDialog").dialog('open');
            $("#policyDialog").html(policydetaildialog);
            return false; */

    //$("#policyDialog");

    //$('#viewDetail').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

I have called this function below

```
<button type="button" class="btn" id="viewDetail" onclick="onViewDetails('<%=policy.getPolicyId()%>');">View details</button>
```

Following is is my html

```
<div id="policyDialog"></div>
```

---

also check below screenshot:
[image]

Comment: post the relevant html please

Comment: remove $('#policyDialog').dialog({ autoOpen: false, }); from document.ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need to create another dialog every time you click the button.

move your dialog declaration out of the click handler:

```
var _PolicyDialog;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#policyDialog").html("");
    _PolicyDialog=$('#policyDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 1000,
        autoResize: false,
        draggable: false,
        hide: null,
        modal: true,
        height: "auto",
        maxHeight: 500,
        maxWidth: 1000,
        minHeight: 450,
        minWidth: 450,
        title: title,
        close: function (e) {
            //e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

and in your ajax function, open dialog like this:

```
_PolicyDialog.dialog("open");
```

Have a look at this <kbd>**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/L5bry73c/)**</kbd>

Comment: I tried this,but not working..first thing - blank dialog gets open on document ready..second thing - first time dialog is showing properly but the second time it gives an error   "Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open' "

Comment: oops my bad, i forgot to mention that you need to assign it to a variable and open it using the variable. ill update my answer

Comment: then you have another piece of code that tries to call the dialog prior to initialization, this code works fine for me...